# Moving a VM from PC to Mac?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, compatibility, vmware-fusion

I have a Windows 7 box on which I, using VMWare Workstation 6.5 am running a VPC with Windows Server 2008. I also have a Mac with Fusion 3.

Can I 'move' the VPC from one platform to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have done this before. Compatibility between VMware Workstation (on the PC) and VMware Fusion (on the Mac) is quite good. You shouldn’t encounter any problems.

However, expect your Windows 2008 virtual machine to want to re-detect some devices after being moved; I don’t think it's a 100% match from one host to another but it’s darn close.